# is it possible to add an error handler to the header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]); in php

Tags: php, error-handling, server, header, location

I am trying to send the browser back tho the page where it came from but with a error or success handler. The headers are spread in various if statements.

`header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]&sucses=successcomment);

header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]&error=sqlerror);

header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]&error=invalidcomment);`

This code is not working. How can i get my handler to get sent back to the page aswell?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`"Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "&error=sqlerror");`

it was incorrectly concatenated, it works now